# What do you want Jon Skeet to sign for you at DevDays?

Tags: discussion, fun, devdays, devdays-2009

Jon Skeet has recently [agreed to sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8934/will-there-be-any-book-signing-opportunities-at-devdays) items at DevDays London. Now is your chance to declare what you want the Skeeter to sign for you within reason<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm lying. No it doesn't have to be within reason.

Comment: It's Friday afternoon somewhere!

Comment: Reason not required but it has to be *within reason* :( That's a sham if I've ever seen one.

Comment: Ian: I should have probably worded that differently. It does -not- have to be within reason.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it would be Friday afternoon in Jon Skeet's neck of the woods.

Comment: Reported since I don't have any close votes yet. Enjoy your brutal moderation!

Comment: It is indeed Friday afternoon. You're extremely silly, which is a good thing.

Comment: Maybe we need "FridayAfternoonOverflow - the site where it's always Friday afternoon."

Comment: Welbog: It's a good thing I'm not a mod here yet! I would be in a pickle having to respond to my own post!

Comment: `<brutalModeration>thwack</brutalModeration>`

Comment: "I'll sign anything you like (within reason)." - Jon Skeet!!!

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Can I just submit a report to have you increase my rep to a billion so I don't have to report things like this to you anymore?

Comment: Of course you can! It won't help of course (not least: I have no ability to grant rep, and rep doesn't give you extra flags), but feel free!

Comment: @Marc Gravell: OK, submitted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A cheque or contract. Don't worry, I'll fill in the number / specifics later...

Comment: And the oversized fuzzy bunny slippers.

Comment: What, these slippers? http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/pics/calling/pic10.jpg

Comment: That's awesome.

Comment: @Ian: At least I won't have purple hair... http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/pics/grin.jpg

Answer (score 26):

If Jon Skeet signed an unsigned int, would it still be unsigned?

Answer (score 8):

I would ask him to sign my signature.

Comment: Paradox               !

Comment: Next challenge: Jon Skeet must sign a paradox.

Comment: Huh, what does this have to do with obsolete database engines?  :-)

Answer (score 5):

I won't be there, so I can't have him sign anything.

However, my offer still stands, and this time I'll bump it up:

**I will put 100 British Pounds into the pool for Jon to give a talk with his right hand as a sock puppet ([context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/what-will-jon-skeet-present-in-stackoverflow-devdays-in-london-cambridge/8639#8639)).**

Addendum: I'll double the amount if the sock puppet is a pony named TXI.

Comment: That's more like it.

Comment: Does he have to give the sock puppet a funny voice? I don't think it will be as good if he just has to flap a sock puppet around. He should hide behind a podium while doing a funny voice for the pony puppet.

Comment: Mr Flibble says: "Use Joda Time, boys!"

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKHLOo1WgDQ for non-Red Dwarf fans. I'm not wearing a gingham dress though.

Comment: The puppet talk **must be filmed**. Even if nothing else is filmed, this must be!

Answer (score 3):

The Queen's forehead.

Comment: I would be terribly impressed if the queen visited Dev Days.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get him to sign his name directly onto a boolean value, just cuz he probably could ; )

Comment: Ah yes, the ol' signed boolean type.  Very useful for when negative true != positive false!